# Dirichlet Energy for Graphs, Derivation

Tags: graph-theory, convolution, neural-networks, graph-laplacian, dirichlet-convolution

I would like to prove this formulation of the Dirichlet Energy for Graph Neural Networks $$
\begin{aligned}
E(\mathbf{X}) &=\frac{1}{d_{i}} \sum_{j \in \mathcal{N}(i)} w_{i j}\left\|\mathbf{x}_{i}-\mathbf{x}_{j}\right\|^{2} \\
&=\operatorname{trace}\left(\mathbf{X} \Delta \mathbf{X}^{\mathrm{T}}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

---

The background information for Graph Neural Networks in this case
Where $\mathbf{X}$ is a matrix of stacked $\mathbf{x}_{i}$.

$$
\begin{aligned}
&(\Delta \mathbf{x})_{i}=\frac{1}{d_{i}} \sum_{j \in \mathcal{N}(i)} w_{i j}\left(\mathbf{x}_{i}-\mathbf{x}_{j}\right)\\
&\text { (normalized) Laplacian matrix }\\
&\Delta=\mathbf{D}^{-1}(\mathbf{D}-\mathbf{W})=\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{D}^{-1} \mathbf{W}\\
&\text { Degree matrix } \mathbf{D}=\left[\begin{array}{lll}
d_{1} & & \\
& \ddots & \\
& & d_{n}
\end{array}\right]
\end{aligned}
$$ and $$d_{i} = 
\sum_{j \in \mathcal{N}(i)} w_{i j}
$$

---

I'm having trouble, as I feel there should be an extra summation for i. I start off like   $$\frac{1}{d_{i}} \sum_{j \in \mathcal{N}(i)} w_{i j}\left\|\mathbf{x}_{i}-\mathbf{x}_{j}\right\|^{2} \\$$ = $$\mathbf{x_{i}}^{T}\mathbf{x_{i}}-\dfrac{2}{d_{i}}\sum w_{ij}\mathbf{x_{i}}^{T}\mathbf{x_{j}}+\dfrac{1}{d_{i}}\sum w_{ij}\mathbf{x_{j}}^{T}\mathbf{x_{j}}$$ but don't know how to proceed,